# About using method "print" etc. in ERB for metaprogramming

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, template-engine, erb, output-buffering

I am using ERB via console for metaprogramming (for math software). For example, I have file `test.erb` containing

```
text line before ruby
<%=  'via <%='  %>
<%  print 'print'  %>
<%  puts  'puts'   %>
text line after ruby
```

When I parse it by `$ erb test.erb`, I get the following output

```
printputs
text line before ruby
via <%=


text line after ruby
```

I am not surprised by it, but wonder if there is a good way to catch output of `print` method and put it at the place where it is called in the ERB template?

```
text line before ruby
via <%=
print
puts
text line after ruby
```

Imagine that I have a complex construction, where I would prefer to print instead of collecting output in a string inside `<%= %>`.

---

**Update**

Just to illustrate the answer of Brian:

```
text line before ruby
<%= '<%=' %>
% print 'print'
% puts 'puts'
% E = _erbout
% E << '_erbout'+"\n"
text line after ruby
```

Parsing the file `$ erb test.erb`:

```
printputs
text line before ruby
<%=
_erbout
text line after ruby
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain if this helps in your particular case, but consider looking at some examples using the _erbout method

```
text line before ruby
<%=  'via <%='  %>
<% _erbout << 'print' %>
<% _erbout << 'puts'  %>
text line after ruby
```

Hope this gets you somewhere.

Comment: `_erbout` seems dead now.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, one can redefine `Kernel#p` method:

#### file: p_for_erb.rb

```
module Kernel
  alias :p_super :p

  def p *args
    if args.empty?
      @@_erbout
    elsif args.first.class == Hash
      @@_erbout = args.first[:init]
    else
      args.each { |a| @@_erbout << a }
    end
  end
end
```

...and then do similar to this:

#### file: mytest.erb

```
text before ruby
% require 'p_for_erb'
% p init: _erbout # to initialize class variable @@_erbout
% p "my p output"
```

Command `$ erb mytest.erb` produces

```
text before ruby
my p output
```